# How can i save space in array which is not being used?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, data-structures, realloc

If I create an array of size 10 and only 2 elements are stored in array so remaining spaces gets wasted. so how can I solve this problem? (by data structure)

Comment: Creating an array of size 2? Would that be an option?

Comment: If the array was dynamically allocated, you can simply use realloc().

Comment: @ Daniele yes but there is any way i can avoid that by using data structure?

Comment: If you mean a `struct` you can only reduce the array length if the `struct` contains an allocated pointer to the array, not the array itself.

Comment: "*i can avoid that*" avoid exactly what? Some more context might help.

Comment: @alk maybe he's referring to using a linked list

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much. If you sometimes need 10 elements, but sometimes only use 2, that is not a big problem. Most solutions with dynamic allocations will actually add more code bytes than you save data bytes, unless the elements are huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a simple linked list instead of an array, or if you would need to use an array, then you should use [`realloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/), which would shrink the array to use only 2 cells, instead of 10.
, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int* ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    ptr[0] = 4;
    ptr[1] = 13;
    ptr =  realloc(ptr, 2 * sizeof(int));
    printf("%d %d\n", ptr[0], ptr[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 4 13

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem

Comment: @NachiketMore then *accept* my answer please. You do that by clicking the tick on the left of my post.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you would use dynamic memory allocation. This means calling `malloc` to acquire an initial amount of memory, followed by `realloc` if necessary when space runs out, and `free` at the end, to return the memory to the arena. Here is a function that reads a line from the standard input. It returns dynamically allocated memory

```
#define INITALLOC  16  /* #chars initally alloced */
#define ALLOCSTEP   8  /* #chars to realloc by */
int getline(char **dynline)
{
    int i, c;
    size_t nalloced;  /* #chars currently alloced */

    if ((*dynline = malloc(INITALLOC)) == NULL)
        return -1;  /* return -1 on mem. err */
    nalloced = INITALLOC;
    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++i) {
        /* buffer is full; request more mem */
        if (i == nalloced)
            if ((*dynline = realloc(*dynline, nalloced += STEP)) == NULL)
                return 0;
        /* store the newly read character */
        (*dynline)[i] = c;
    }
    /* zero terminate the string */
    (*dynline)[i] = '\0';

    if (c == EOF)
        return 0;  /* return 0 on EOF */

    return 1;
}
```

The user of this function is responsible for freeing the memory. Ex:

```
char *buf;
printf("What is your full name?\n");
if (getline(&buf) > 0)
    puts(buf);
free(buf);
```

Of course, there is still some waste, but that is impossible to solve using an array. Consider a linked list https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/linked%20lists.html